# How to send data to httphandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, httphandler

I have a link on a page, which does a post back.

```
    otherOptionsContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<a href='{0}' onclick='return {1}.exportItems();'>Export</a><br/>", exportURL, this._clientInstanceName)));
```

and http handler

```
                byte[] ms_excel = some_params_from_code
                MemoryStream ms_excel_tream = new MemoryStream(ms_excel);
                context.Response.ContentType = CONTENT_TYPE_MS_EXCEL;
                String dateNow=DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy_HH_mm", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=Export_{0}.xls", dateNow));
                ms_excel_tream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
                ms_excel_tream.Close();
```

I need to send some_params_from_code to the httpHandler. I have some restrictions. 
      1. Don't use query string
      2. Don't use Cookies

I was  trying to send data using ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "_Layouts/blah/blahHandler.ashx",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'key1':'value1'},
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnComplete,
        error: OnFail
    });
```

but http handler writes another response object. Or another context comes to handler.

Comment: where is the `ssome_params_from_code` supposed to come from? server side? client side passed in your json object? its not reallty clear

Comment: ssome_params_from_code supposed to come from the server side. in my example with json I passed it from the server side to the client side and from client send using json.

Comment: so its like every other object you are using on the server side (query string/cookies are irellevant here). If its something you get from db you can get it with a db call, if its a session dependant object, you can retrieve it from session, etc. You need to provide more information about this variable and what exactly doesnt work..

Comment: When I address to my handler clicking on the link ( <a href = "_Layouts/blah/blahHandler.ashx" />) I get my excel file. But to pass some_params_from_code to handler I use Cookie. And when I use ajax request I can't get my file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your only restrictions are not to use a query string and cookies, why not to use form post? Consider this dummy example.

In your HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="DefaultHandler.ashx" method="post" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="abc" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="xyz" />
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="form.submit(); return false;">Handle</a>
```

In a handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Received:\n");
    context.Response.Write(context.Request.Form["field1"]);
    context.Response.Write("\n");
    context.Response.Write(context.Request.Form["field2"]);
    context.Response.Write("\n");
}
```

Adjust it for your needs. You could create the form dynamically in your JavaScript and set up fields as necessary.