# How to process a HTTP POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

I have a HTTP handler which receives a HTTP POST.
HTTP POST message with header is -

```
POST /ibe/example.com HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 445
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Host: 202.177.46.142

charset=UTF-8&param1=val1&param2=val2
```

Handler in my code is -

```
            var V1 = context.Request["param1"];
            var V2 = context.Request["param2"];
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Are V1 and V2 null after those lines?

Comment: First of all set Request.Method = "POST";

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using:

```
var V1 = context.Request.Param["param1"];
var V2 = context.Request.Param["param2"];
```

Taken from this example here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1190337.aspx and here [How to send data to httphandler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11262112/1370442)